# Display taken picture in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Following [the android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image), I am able to take a picture.

```
public class TakePhotoActivity extends Activity {

    private Uri fileUri;
    // I am not sure what this is for yet
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);
        // Show the Up button in the action bar.
        setupActionBar();

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

        startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

    }

    private static Uri getOutputMediaFileUri() {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile());
    }

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        return new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + "IMG_"
                + timeStamp + ".jpg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
            if (RESULT_OK == resultCode) {
//              Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + data.getData(),
//              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to display the picture I just took, using `onActivityResult`. Does anyone have some code to do that?

Edit to show XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".TakePhotoActivity" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it like this:

```
public class TakePhotoActivity extends Activity {

private Uri fileUri;
// I am not sure what this is for yet
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
ImageView image;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_photo);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();
    image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri();
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

and then in here put the bitmap in the imageview like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == 100) {
            try {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), fileUri);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
 image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


                 sendBroadcast(new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                        Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));





        }
```

Comment: I am a beginner. I am looking for something I can understand. I was hoping for something with much fewer codes.

Comment: now how it is, you will get the bitmap at a really high resolution and the sendBroadcast will update your gallery with the picture that you took, then in there just do whatever you want with the bitmap

Comment: if you dont send broadcast like that the picture wont show up in your phone until the next time you turn on your phone

Comment: Many thanks for helping. Upvote since I am no longer seeing an error. However, my emulator is now showing a blank screen. So I will keep investigating, whether it's a emulator issue or not.

Comment: the emulators are horrible with emulating picture taking i think, in your layout do you have an ImageView or something to display the bitmap after you take the picture?

Answer (score 0):

```
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri)
myview.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(b));
```

"myview" is any view object from your layout.  So if your layout contains a RelativeLayout object with id "@+id/myview", then the second line could say:

findViewById(R.id.myview).setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(b));

Comment: I have edited my post to show what I have so far. Are you able to provide the implemented `onActivityResult` method for me? In the mean time, I will be searching for how to create the `myview` you mention. This is my second day learning android.